# Interpreting the messages recieved during synchronisation on geth

Tags: go-ethereum, the-dao, synchronization, import, blockchain-fork

I'm presently synchronising to the Ethereum blockchain using geth.

I'm seeing two types of message and have a bit of an understanding gap in what they mean. The messages are shown below, with my guess at what they mean.

***Synchronisation message type 1:***

```
I0906 10:09:01.619035 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 77e6a5959a5e0529 [eth/63]: timed out DAO fork-check, dropping
```

- `I0906` - *Not sure - a log ID?*
- `10:09:01.619035` - *time*
- `eth/handler.go:295]` - *unsure?*
- `Peer 77e6a5959a5e0529` - *the peer from which the message originates*
- `[eth/63]: timed out DAO fork-check, dropping` - *error code and message*

***Synchronisation message type 2:***

```
I0906 10:16:21.875217 core/blockchain.go:963] imported 2048 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 4408 txs in 10.3195903s. #774796 [7fcf4021 / a0a4535a]
```

- `I0906` - *Not sure - a log ID?*
- `10:16:21.875217` - *time*
- `core/blockchain.go:963]` - *unsure?*
- `imported 2048 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 4408 txs in 10.3195903s.` - *number of blocks downloaded, number of transactions and time taken to download - does "imported" have special meaning?*
- `#774796` - *block number, first or last of 2048?*
- `[7fcf4021 / a0a4535a]` - *don't know*

**What does each segment of the above message types mean?**

Is there a man page related to this?

Comment: The `.go` stuff refers to the code, like https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/blockchain.go#L964

Comment: @XavierLeprêtreB9lab thanks, yes just been looking at that code. Presently trying to figure out the glog/logs behaviour - thinking that the `I0906` is created when a log is initiated.... but can't find relevant code atm.

Answer (score 2):

***Message type 1***, from the [relevant code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/handler.go#L295):

```
// If we're DAO hard-fork aware, validate any remote peer with regard to the hard-fork
    if daoBlock := pm.chainconfig.DAOForkBlock; daoBlock != nil {
        // Request the peer's DAO fork header for extra-data validation
        if err := p.RequestHeadersByNumber(daoBlock.Uint64(), 1, 0, false); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        // Start a timer to disconnect if the peer doesn't reply in time
        p.forkDrop = time.AfterFunc(daoChallengeTimeout, func() {
            glog.V(logger.Warn).Infof("%v: timed out DAO fork-check, dropping", p)
            pm.removePeer(p.id)
        })
        // Make sure it's cleaned up if the peer dies off
        defer func() {
            if p.forkDrop != nil {
                p.forkDrop.Stop()
                p.forkDrop = nil
            }
}()
```

My interpretation is that any peers not(?) participating in the theDAO hard fork are dropped from the list of peers used to import blocks from.

- `I0906` - ***Still don't know?***
- `10:09:01.619035` - *time*
- `eth/handler.go:295]` - *[file and line of relevant code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/handler.go#L295)*
- `Peer 77e6a5959a5e0529` - *the peer from which the message originates*
- `[eth/63]:` - `p` *message code?*
- `timed out DAO fork-check, dropping` - *message*

***Message type 2***, from the [relevant code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/blockchain.go#L963):

```
    if (stats.queued > 0 || stats.processed > 0 || stats.ignored > 0) && bool(glog.V(logger.Info)) {
        tend := time.Since(tstart)
        start, end := chain[0], chain[len(chain)-1]
        glog.Infof("imported %d block(s) (%d queued %d ignored) including %d txs in %v. #%v [%x / %x]\n", stats.processed, stats.queued, stats.ignored, txcount, tend, end.Number(), start.Hash().Bytes()[:4], end.Hash().Bytes()[:4])
    }
go self.postChainEvents(events, coalescedLogs)
```

- `I0906` - ***still unsure*** - I think it might be created when `glog` is initialised
- `10:16:21.875217` - *time*
- `core/blockchain.go:963]` - *[file and line of code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/blockchain.go#L963)*
- `imported 2048 block(s)` - 2048 = `stats.processed` *number of processed blocks*
- `(0 queued 0 ignored)` - `stats.queued, stats.ignored`
- `including 4408 txs in 10.3195903s.` - *number of transactions* `txcount` *and time taken to process* `tend`
- `#774796` - *last block number (of the 2048 imported),* `end.Number()`
- `[7fcf4021 / a0a4535a]` - *first 4 bytes of hashes of the first and last blocks (of the 2048 imported),* `start.Hash().Bytes()[:4], end.Hash().Bytes()[:4]`

As regards the `I0906` I *think* it relates to the `tag` parameter of `[glog][2]`, but I'm still not sure:

```
func create(tag string, t time.Time) (f *os.File, filename string, err error) { ...
```